# Difference between conceptual help and API help in .NET?

Tags: .net

I want to write some good docs for my .NET project - it's a class library.  Should I generate conceptual help aswell as API help - what are the differences and what kind of informatio should I put in the conceptual help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptual help is about concepts - "what is XML".

API help is about the API - How does `XmlReader.Read()` work?

Comment: Both are important. The first let you understand how the framework internally fits together, the second tells you what a specific method does in the whole framework.